# Populate combo box with table values

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans, combobox

**EDIT(NEW):**

Still haven't figured out how to populate the `cboxCustomers`. I've been at it for the past day or two, but without luck.

In case anyone can help: http://pastebin.com/e5wibRYw

I went from `cats` to `customers`, btw.

I tried `Mr. Xymon's` approach, but didn't implement it correctly since it didn't work.

Whatever event I used to handle the population I always got `NullPointerException` for whatever control/event I was trying to use.

**OLD:**

<strike>There's a `JForm`. On it, there's a single combo box. Also have a single table with cats - `cats`. Each cat has `id`, and `catName`.</strike>

What I wanted to do was when I click on the combo box, thus expanding it, populate it with all `id` of cats that are found in `cats` table.

**SLOVED. Asnwer below.**
Unfortunately I receive numerous `unreported exception java.sql.SQLException` from the lines I've indicated with `>`:

```
private void cboxCatsMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        // create an array list to be filled with cat's ids
        ArrayList<String> cats = new ArrayList<String>();
        String query = "SELECT id FROM cats ORDER BY id";
        >java.sql.PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(query);

        >ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(query);

        >while(rs.next()){
            >String cat = rs.getString("id");
            // add cat's ids tp the array list
            cats.add(cat);
        }

        >rs.close();

        // populate the combo box
        DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(cats.toArray());
        cboxCats.setModel(model);
    }
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

I think I fixed it. I just had to wrap all of the highlighted lines of code together into one big `try-catch` statement that would catch `SQLException`. Problem is - the combo box doesn't get populated with `id` values when I expand it. Why is that? Am I using the wrong event?

Comment: Post the full exception text please. Also you'll want to do any database querying in a background thread such as that which is provided by a SwingWorker object.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Again, you should do all database querying in a background thread. Why are you trying to fill the combobox on mouseClick as that makes no sense. It will take time to query the database, and it will likely mess with Swing's ability to open the combo box. Why not fill the combobox in advance?

Comment: Yes. That makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: In answer to your EDIT, insert your code within the constructor or create a method to perform the task then call it from your constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't better to populate your combo box with cat's name instead of the id? I came up with a different solution by directly adding field value into model instead of using ArrayList. You have to perform it within the constructor to populate the combo box upon loading the form.

```
DefaultComboBoxModel list = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
JComboBox cbo_cats = new JComboBox(list);


// at constructor or a user-defined method that's called from constructor
   try{     
      // assume that all objects were all properly defined
      s = con.createStatement();
      s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cats ORDER BY catName");
      rs = s.getResultSet();
      while(rs.next()){
         //int id = rs.getInt("id");
         //list.addElement(id);

         String c = rs.getString("catName");
         list.addElement(c);
      }
   }catch(Exception err){
      System.out.println(err);
   }
```

As you can see I didn't use prepared statements but you can easily change that.

Comment: Hmm. The only problem I see with this is that the combo box populates only when the form loads. Thing is my program has tabs. So the first tab allows user to view data about each cat, update a particular cat, remove and add a new one. Second tab contains the combo box. So let's say the form loaded, filled the combo box with already existing cats using your way. Now, what if I go and create a new cat, update existing, or delete one on the first tab of my application. That will change the table in the database which means the combo box will contain outdated information. What can I do about that?

Comment: There's a remedy for that. Create a method, let's say fetchCategory(), that contains codes for populating the combo box. That's the same method that you're going to call from the constructor. What you need to add in the beginning is a code that removes all elements from the combo box using DefaultComboBoxModel object, which in my example I named it list. So it would be like this, list.removeAllElements(); Lastly, just call the method fetchCategory(); after performing every category operation such as update, delete, insert. That should update the contents of your combo box.

Comment: For the `fetchCategoty()`, did you mean something like this - http://pastebin.com/JHH0yLhD Ignore the confusion between `cats` and `customers`

Comment: Exactly. So that would empty the combo box before reloading the updated cats.